# How does `isInstanceOf` work?

Tags: scala, subtype

Assume, we have:

```
class B
class A extends B
trait T
```

Then it holds:

```
val a: A with T = new A with T 
a.isInstanceOf[B]  // result is true !
```

Is it right to say, the `isInstanceOf` method checks, if there is at least one type (not all types) which matches the right hand side in a subtype relationship?

At first look, I thought a value with type `A with T` can not be a subtype of `B`, because `A` **and** `T` are not both subtypes of `B`. But it is `A` **or** `T` is a subtype of `B` -- is that right ?

Comment: Here a quick overview of object equality http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-eight-scalas-type-hierarchy-and-object-equality/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`isInstanceOf` looks if there is a corresponding entry in the inheritance chain. The chain of `A with T` includes `A`, `B` and `T`, so `a.isInstanceOf[B]` must be true.

edit:

Actually the generated byte code calls javas `instanceof`, so it would be `a instanceof B` in java. A little more complex call like `a.isInstanceOf[A with T]` would be `(a instanceof A) && (a instanceof T)`.

Comment: Thank you for the background information, that helped a lot. Do you know where I can find more background information about the Scala's `isInstanceOf` method ? The Scala API does not tell much about it.

Comment: There's not much to tell. It is just `instanceof`.

Answer (score 13):

> At first look, I thought a value with type A with T can not be a
>   subtype of B

There's are two misconceptions here. First, that the static type of an instance has any bearing on the result of `isInstanceOf`: there is none. To be clear, when doing `a.isInstanceOf[B]`, the fact that `a` is of type `A with T` *is not relevant*.

The method `isInstanceOf` is implemented at the bytecode level by the JVM. It looks at the class information *every instance carries*, and checks whether `B` one of the classes (the class of the instance itself and its ancestors), or one of the implemented interfaces. That's the "is-a" relationship: "a is a B".

Technically, `isInstanceOf` is part of Java's reflection, where it is known as `instanceof`.

The second misconception is the inheritance can somehow *remove* a parent type. That never happens: inheritance only adds types, never removes them. The type `A with T` is an `A`, a `B`, a `T`, an `AnyVal` and an `Any`. So even if `isInstanceOf` did look at the type `A with T`, it would still return true.

Comment: Do you know how i can prove `Null` and `Nothing` are sub-types of all things in the REPL? `"A".isInstanceOf[Null]` errors? as does `Nothing`? I guess that makes sense; ie `"A" instanceof null` wouldn't work in Java. Do I just have to take the docs word for it?!

Comment: @Toby `Nothing` does not exist in Java, since it treats classes and primitives and distinct things, and `instanceof` only pertains to the former. Also, `Null` does not exist either in Java, which has no concept of a "bottom".